# Infopath form not submitting to correct library upon creation

Tags: 2010, infopath, content-type, form, library

I am using SharePoint 2010 with infopath. Currently I have a form library set up to submit infopath forms. The library is using the infopath form for the content type when creating new items. The problem I am encountering is when I create a new item in the library with that content type, the new item is saving to a completely different library. I am not sure why this is occurring, but I need the forms I create to be added to the correct library for a workflow to work. I have tried republishing the form content type but it doesn't seem to be changing its association to the library. Any suggestions for how I could continue troubleshooting would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 scenario which you should verify.

Scenario-1:

- Go to "File-> Publish" and verify your target library.

Scenario-2:

- Verify your data connection once because there might be wrong target specified there.

Let me know if above scenario defines your problem. Thanks